# SVG animation in snake

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I'm trying to animate in snake way a text, using SVG, like this:

[image]

My goals is make the text animate, but in the same place. I already did this:

```js
var textPath = document.getElementById('texto'),
    comprimento = textPath.getAttribute('startOffset');

var animador = setInterval(function () {
    comprimento--;
    textPath.setAttribute('startOffset', comprimento);
}, 10);
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
    <defs>
        <path id="myPath" d="m 40,130 c 0,0 60,-80 120,-80 60,0 74.00337,80 140,80 65.99663,0 80,-80 140,-80 60,0 120,80 120,80" />
    </defs>
    <text style="stroke: #000000;">
        <textPath startOffset="240" id="texto" xlink:href="#myPath">Testing this text</textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

As you can see, the animation is moving to the <-, how fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ++ instead of --, then once the offsetValue hits 240 (your original starting value when you went backwards) stop incrementing it.

```js
var textPath = document.getElementById('texto'),
    comprimento = textPath.getAttribute('startOffset');

var animador = setInterval(function () {
    if (comprimento < 240) {
      comprimento++;
      textPath.setAttribute('startOffset', comprimento);
    }
}, 10);
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
    <defs>
        <path id="myPath" d="m 40,130 c 0,0 60,-80 120,-80 60,0 74.00337,80 140,80 65.99663,0 80,-80 140,-80 60,0 120,80 120,80" />
    </defs>
    <text style="stroke: #000000;">
        <textPath startOffset="0" id="texto" xlink:href="#myPath">Testing this text</textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: can i stop in the final @Robert?

Comment: I've changed the answer to stop. You could cancel the setInterval timer too.